# Bringing Values Down

Tags: sql-server

My result looks like this (Output1):

```
 ID     Year    YearWeek    Week    ID1         (No column name)

479474  2017    201718      18          479474  201718
479474  2017    201719      19          NULL    NULL
479474  2017    201720      20          NULL    NULL
479474  2017    201721      21          479474  201721
479474  2017    201722      22          NULL    NULL
479474  2017    201723      23          479474  201723
479474  2017    201724      24          479474  201724
```

However, I would like for it to look like the following:

```
 ID     Year    YearWeek    Week    ID1         (No column name)

479474  2017    201718      18          479474  201718
479474  2017    201719      19          NULL    201718
479474  2017    201720      20          NULL    201718
479474  2017    201721      21          479474  201721
479474  2017    201722      22          NULL    201721
479474  2017    201723      23          479474  201723
479474  2017    201724      24          479474  201724
```

Can someone please make some suggestions to make code so that the values in (No column name) are dragged down?  The values are 201718, 201721, 201723, and 201724.

Comment: What version of SQL Serve are you using? LAG() is 2012+.

Comment: I am using 2012

Comment: So the LAG() function should work.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how it should be used?  I have never used this function before?  Thank  you

Comment: Actually looking further into it, because of the `NULL` the `LAG` function may not work. I'm trying to replicate it now.

Answer (score 2):

Take this for a spin...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    YearWeek INT NOT NULL,
    [Week] INT NOT NULL,
    ID1 int NULL 
    );

INSERT #TestData (ID, Year, YearWeek, Week, ID1) VALUES
    (479474, 2017, 201718, 18, 479474),
    (479474, 2017, 201719, 19, NULL  ),
    (479474, 2017, 201720, 20, NULL  ),
    (479474, 2017, 201721, 21, 479474),
    (479474, 2017, 201722, 22, NULL  ),
    (479474, 2017, 201723, 23, 479474),
    (479474, 2017, 201724, 24, 479474);

--  SELECT * FROM #TestData td

--============================================================

SELECT 
    td.ID, td.Year, td.YearWeek, td.Week, td.ID1,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(td.YearWeek AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(td.ID1 AS BINARY(4))) OVER (ORDER BY td.YearWeek ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), 1, 4) AS INT)
FROM
    #TestData td;
```

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Comment: Again @AllisonCoder you should really consider accepting Jason's correct answer, as well as answers on the rest of your questions

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the lack of a catch-all in the case-statement following the CTE.

Update your Select statement to read as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Y.*,  
    CASE 
        WHEN Y.[ID1] IS NOT NULL THEN Y.[YearWeek] 
        ELSE NULL   ----> ADDED TO HAVE A NULL WHEN THERE'S NO VALUE IN PREVIOUS COLUMN
    END AS Column1 
FROM Y
ORDER BY Y.[Customer ID], Y.Year, Y.[YearWeek], Y.Week;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not work.  I am trying to bring down the YearWeek value anywhere where there is a null located like in the final table.